# Visual Studio 2013 AssemblyVersion "99.0.*" always results in "99.0.0.0"

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2013, versioning

I'm using a `GlobalAssemblyVersion.cs` file that sets the versions for all my projects. The file is in the root solution folder and is included as a link in all my projects. The file contents is as follows:

```
using System.Reflection;   
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("99.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("99.0.*")]
[assembly : AssemblyInformationalVersion("99.0 internal")]
```

When I build my solution, the assembly versions are always set to "99.0.0.0". I thought that Visual Studio was supposed to substitute the day number and seconds since midnight for the last two items (build/revision).

Any ideas why this isn't working? Did this behaviour change in VS2013 or is it something I'm doing?

Comment: As far as I can remember, the automatic numbers used by Visual Studio have never really made any real sense, or at least were of no real value to me.

I just set all local development to X.Y.0.0, and have build server scripting that assigns sensible values for the build and revision numbers.

Comment: Agreed, I also do that on my build server, but that doesn't answer my question. There is value (to me) in having my assemblies versioned correctly. I have had this work in the past and I'm just wondering why I can't get it to work now.

Comment: @Hans I think I'm missing your point. The 99 value isn't important. What's important is that the auto-incrementing isn't working and I need to know why. I use 99 to differentiate private builds from those built on the build server, which generates its own version numbers based on SemVer.

Comment: @Hans Initially I tried "9999" and got a compilation error ;-) I will try a smaller number and see what happens.

Comment: @Hans, for what it's worth, "42.0.*" results in "42.0.0.0" - same problem.

Comment: I think I can see what is going on. I opened my assembly in dotPeek and that reported the expected version number, so it looks like it is working correctly. I was looking at the AssemblyFileVersion in Explorer, which I am also setting to "x.y.*". The compiler is silently replacing my "*" with "0.0". How confusing!

Answer (score 1):

AssemblyFileVersion does not support *.

Change this to read:

```
using System.Reflection;   
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("99.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("99.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("99.0 internal")]
```

To add to this:
The Automatic Build and revision numbers do actually make sense. (Refer [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)

The Build is the number of days since 1 January 2000 and the Revision is the number of seconds since midnight (local time) divided by 2.  Given any auto-incremented build, you can identify exactly when the build happened.